# Add target=blank in WordPress function for WP-Members

Tags: wordpress

How make this code add `target=_blank` on return, so when user clicks they will be redirected?

```php
add_filter( 'wpmem_forgot_link', 'my_forgot_link', 10, 2 );
function my_forgot_link( $link, $tag ) {
    // Using home_url() instead makes your filter portable.
    return 'http://test.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the [`wpmem_forgot_link_str`](https://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/docs/filter-hooks/wpmem_forgot_link_str/) hook instead, which would allow you to add `target="blank"` to the HTML being generated.

An example of what you'd need:

```php
add_filter( 'wpmem_forgot_link_str', 'my_forgot_link_str', 10, 2 );
function my_forgot_link_str( $str, $link ) {
    return "<a href=\"$link\" target=\"blank\">Forgot your password?</a>";
}
```

Comment: and where i can add the specific url "http://test.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"

Comment: You can modify/override `$link` before the `return` statement. IE, add `$link = "https://example.com/other-link";`. If you don't modify `$link`, then it will be the default lost password link: `http://test.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`.